# Is the null/empty set both a subset of and disjoint from every non-empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any set (nonempty or otherwise) $A, \varnothing \subseteq A$.

Two sets are said to be disjoint if they contain no elements in common, so for any nonempty set $A, \varnothing$ is disjoint from $A$.

Can the null set therefore be considered BOTH a subset of and disjoint from $A$? Doesn't that contradict the definitions of these terms?

Comment: Where is the contradiction? Suppose, by contradiction, that $A$ and $\varnothing$ are not disjoint. Then, there exists $x\in A \cap \varnothing$. In particular, $x\in \varnothing$, which is a contradiction. Then, $A$ and $\varnothing$ are disjoint.

Comment: It is both a subset of and disjoint from every set, empty or nonempty.

Comment: It's not a contradiction at all; rather, it's one example of many of the weirdness of the empty set from a "natural language" perspective. An easier-to-digest example might be: "every element of $\emptyset$ is positive" and "every element of $\emptyset$ is negative" are each true, and don't contradict each other.

Answer (score 5):

Going straight to the definition: $A\subseteq B$ if whenever $a\in A$ we must have that $a\in B$. Well if $A=\emptyset$ this is true for every $B$ since there is no $a\in A$. Hence $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set.

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint if $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Clearly if $B=\emptyset$ then this is true for all $A$.

It may conflict with the English definition of the words, but math is not English. Words mean different things.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this may answer your question.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary set.

Suppose that $A\cap \varnothing\neq \varnothing$ (suppose they are not disjoint).

Then **there exists $x\in \varnothing$** such that $x\notin A$, which is a contradiction since the empty set contains no elements by definition.

Now, suppose that $\varnothing \nsubseteq A$. Again, we can see that this cannot be true since this would imply that there exists some element in $\varnothing$ which is not an element of $A$.

So in particular, the empty set is a subset of **every** set, and also that the empty set is disjoint with every set. Almost every time you prove something regarding the empty set, the best route to go is usually to use a proof by contradiction, since working with the empty set is almost always counter intuitive.